# Inverse width transition from left to right to right to left

Tags: css, width, css-transitions

I'm reverse engineering the navigation in http://dreamelectronic.com/ (must use desktop for correct view) but in my own way.

I practically have it down, spot on, but i have one little issue i need to fix to get it just right. what i have is 2 `div`'s that are on top of eachother and they both increase the width of the top border as see in the website. BUT one `div` starts at the center and stretches from center to the right and the other one stretches from the left to the center (if that makes sense). i need the second div (`div2` if you go and read my code from CSSDeck) to start from the center and stretch to the left.

What i have tried is to use `transform: rotateX(-180deg);` as suggested from one of the answers from another question, i also tried to set the `test-align: right;` on the `div2` also suggested. I tried `animation-direction: alternate;` too but no cake.

I have come across several similar situations on here but none have worked for me so far.

[CSSDeck Project](http://cssdeck.com/labs/u36uc0it)

Many thanks if i can get this last detail down!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the below properties on your `div2`:

```
div2 {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  ...
}
```

***Snippet:***

```css
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px;
}
li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
div1 {
    margin-left: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 3px solid #D50;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
div2 {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3;
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 3px solid #D50;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
men a {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: color .4s ease;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
men a:hover {
    color: #D50;
}
men a:hover~div1 {
    width: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
}
men a:hover~div2 {
    width: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <men>
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
      <div1></div1>
      <div2></div2>
    </men>
  </li>
  <li>
    <men>
      <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <div1></div1>
      <div2></div2>
    </men>
  </li>
  <li>
    <men>
      <a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
      <div1></div1>
      <div2></div2>
    </men>
  </li>
  <li>
    <men>
      <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
      <div1></div1>
      <div2></div2>
    </men>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So your `div1` is pushed using `margin-left` (which you already had) and your `div2` is first forced to `float` from `right` and then pushed using `margin-right`.

Hope this helps.

P.S. Don't forget to *close* the `div2`.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks! Finally finished

Answer (score 0):

You can use positioning for "right-to-left" div:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u5ofdp9m/1/